# Pop up djstripe payments modal without button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, stripe-payments

Since I only have one djstripe subscription plan, I'm trying to get my djstripe payments/subscribe page to pop up the payments modal without a click. The JavaScript that works with the click of a button is this:

```
$(function() {   
    $('body').on("click", '.djstripe-subscribe button[type=submit]', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      // retrieve current $(".djstripe-subscribe")
      var $form = $(e.target).parents('form'),
          token = function(res) {
            $form.find("input[name=stripe_token]").val(res.id);
            $("button[type=submit]").attr("disabled", "true");
            $('#in-progress').modal({"keyboard": false})
            $('.progress-bar').animate({width:'+=100%'}, 2000);
            $form.trigger("submit");
          };
      StripeCheckout.open({
        key:         "{{ STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY }}",
        name:        'Payment Method',
        panelLabel:  'Add Payment Method',
        token:       token
      });

      return false;
    });
    {% if PLAN_LIST|length > 1 %}
      $('.djstripe-change-plan').click(function(e){
          $("button[type=submit]").attr("disabled", "true");
          $('#in-progress').modal({"keyboard": false})
          $('.progress-bar').animate({width:'+=100%'}, 2000);
          var $form = $(this);
          $form.trigger("submit");
      });
    {% endif %}

});
```

I've been able to get the modal to pop up by removing the wrapper function and putting the script in a document ready function, like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(e) {
      // retrieve current $(".djstripe-subscribe")
      var $form = $(e.target).parents('form'),
          token = function(res) {
            $form.find("input[name=stripe_token]").val(res.id);
            $("button[type=submit]").attr("disabled", "true");
            $('#in-progress').modal({"keyboard": false})
            $('.progress-bar').animate({width:'+=100%'}, 2000);
            $form.trigger("submit");
          };
      StripeCheckout.open({
        key:         "{{ STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY }}",
        name:        'Payment Method',
        panelLabel:  'Add Payment Method',
        token:       token
      });

      return false;
    });
    {% if PLAN_LIST|length > 1 %}
      $('.djstripe-change-plan').click(function(e){
          $("button[type=submit]").attr("disabled", "true");
          $('#in-progress').modal({"keyboard": false})
          $('.progress-bar').animate({width:'+=100%'}, 2000);
          var $form = $(this);
          $form.trigger("submit");
      });
    {% endif %}
```

However, this eliminates the .djstripe-subscribe button[type=submit] selector, causes errors with e.preventDefault() unless I remove it as shown in this code snippet, and makes the "server update" that comes up after a payment method is submitted crank eternally with no results. How can I get the modal to pop up and update successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could do this is using jQuery's .click() method (https://api.jquery.com/click/) on the first version of the code, but 'click' the element on page load?

Comment: Here's the code that worked from phildini: https://gist.github.com/phildini/88c136ed3f816bb7fea4